# Easing functions not having any effect in skitter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-easing, skitter-slider

I am using skitter to create a slideshow and it looks like the easing functions I provide with the easing_default key are not having any effect. Here is my code:

```
$('.skitter').skitter({
    auto_play: false,
    dots: false,
    velocity: 0.1,
    easing_default: 'linear'
});
```

I tried a lot of values for the easing property like 'easeInQuart' etc. and the animation always seemed to move forward in the same way. I even tried some invalid values like 'fdoijhrb' and it did not give any errors.

What am I doing wrong here?

The library adds easing effects like this in its source code:

```
var easing = (this.settings.easing_default == '') ? 'easeInQuad' : this.settings.easing_default;
```

Link to the API: https://skitter-slider.net/options.html

Link to fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/85uqdxhr/

Thanks.

Comment: Cant say for sure but a cursory look looks like the "easing" effects are not built-into the plugin. Otherwise did you find a list of easing effects in the documentation?

Comment: Thanks @GetSet. :) I have added a line of code from the library to show how they determine which effect to add. I have also included the easing library that they recommend.

Comment: Ok, I just looked. But it appears that in those docs for the easing library (in ref to "jquery.easing.1.3.js") that there is no "linear" easing effect. Maybe it's spelled differently than what you have in your code if it's built into jquery itself.

Comment: I have tried other effects included in the library source code as well and none of them work. I will create a working demo. :)

Comment: Ok because I'm curious too, seems like a cool slideshow plugin otherwise

Comment: @GetSet Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/85uqdxhr/. Try changing the easing methods. :)

Comment: Alright I'll give it a try

Comment: Could be that there is no perceptible (human wise) difference between cross-fade transitions with the various ease methods. It may be that you will have to see the perceptible differences as it pertains to "motion", e.g. tweening. ... I tried the fiddle.

Comment: I slowed down it a lot. Even if the difference is not perceptible at fast speeds there would be something it slow speeds.